# Moving along the path - strange rotations

Tags: armature, bones

I would like to make an opening gate composed of segments. All segments except the lowest one work fine. The lowest, unfortunately, performs strange rotations when moving along the path. I tried adding new mesh, new empty's, extrude new bone. No good result. I'd appreciate a hint as to what I'm doing wrong. [Link to the video on YT](https://youtu.be/In750W4cLFw)

[image]

Comment: Please share your Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to add the link into your question.

Comment: Link to file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=zNjLjY9r" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/zNjLjY9r/)

Comment: That's very odd! I'm no expert on animation but the only difference I can see between that section and all the others is that the bone roll of the bottom bone is 90° and all the others are -90° but changing that bottom one to match the others makes no difference.   I don't know if anyone else here has an answer now that the blend file is available?

Comment: Hello, you didn't share the link to your file, only a jpg image, please share the link  ;)

Comment: I corrected the link :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not sure what's gone wrong with your file, but here is a much easier solution:
[image]
Run the animation to see it in action.
If you want a different texture on each panel you can apply the array and everything will still work. (I've moved the top front edge of the panel down slightly to show the gaps between panels.)

Comment: Your solution is beautiful BUT will I be able to export this fbx with animation to Unity? I assumed that bones would be needed for the animation to work properly in Unity.

Comment: I'm afraid that I've no idea about any other software. I only ever use Blender here. Maybe someone else can give a solution to your original problem (hello @moonboots)?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found the problem. All empty had to have a location applied, which I didn't. Now the gate opens properly :)

Comment: Ah! Yes they would need that. I thought I'd checked those. :^(